# Installing specific (older) version of OpenCPU

Tags: r, opencpu

How can I install an older version of OpenCPU?

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and installed opencpu as described here https://www.opencpu.org/download.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:opencpu/opencpu-2.2
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y opencpu-server
```

I got version

2.2.**11**-jammy

but I need

2.2.**9**-jammy

I'm using a CRAN snapshot from April 2023 and it contains older version of some R-packages compared to the newest versions installed via the latest opencpu.
Unfortunately, due to other issues, I cannot upgrade to newer snapshot and thus I need an older opencpu-version.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question related to R.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y opencpu-server=2.2.9-jammy`?

Comment: @DanielHoop At https://www.opencpu.org/help.html it is recommended to tag the question both with #r and #opencpu. Sorry if I misunderstood the recommendation.

Comment: @Fastnlight Thanks, I guess that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: running in docker

You can use the docker container for example:

```r
docker run -it -p80:80 opencpu/base:v2.2.9-3
```

Will run opencpu 2.2.9. Open it in your browser: http://localhost/ocpu/info

So you can base your personal app image on that in your `Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM opencpu/base:v2.2.9-3

RUN .....
```

### option 2: copying installers

If you do not want to run in docker, you can still copy old installers from a docker image. So you would have to start the docker (on any machine):

```bash
docker run --rm -it --name mybox --entrypoint=/bin/bash opencpu/ubuntu-22.04:v2.2.9-3
```

And then in another shell copy the files:

```bash
docker cp mybox:/root/opencpu-lib_2.2.9-jammy3_amd64.deb .
docker cp mybox:/root/opencpu-server_2.2.9-jammy3_all.deb .
```

And those `deb` files are the installers that you can install on your server.

Comment: I use a Linux server running Ubuntu and have not the possibility to change to docker.

Comment: OK I have updated my answer. Let me know if you get stuck, I can maybe help you get the installers.